# Couldn't find trained model at C:\Users\TULINC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcpcforqv

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am getting this error

> Couldn't find trained model at C:\Users\TULINC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcpcforqv.

When I evaluate the model. The code is `results=estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn_test)`

What should I do? Could you please help? Because no reason to find the model I used `tempfile.mkdtemp()`. Have you any idea about the error?

```
import  tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import tempfile


tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
FEATURES = ["RowNumber","CustomerId","CreditScore","Age","Tenure","Balance",
"NumOfProducts", "HasCrCard","IsActiveMember", "EstimatedSalary"]
LABEL = 'Exited'

df_train = pd.read_csv("Churn_Modelling.csv", skipinitialspace=True, 
header=0)
df_test = pd.read_csv("Churn_Modelling.csv", skipinitialspace=True, 
header=0)

train_label=df_train[LABEL]
test_label = df_test[LABEL]

def input_fn_train():
    x=tf.constant(df_train),
    y=tf.constant(test_label)
    return x, y

def input_fn_test():
    x=tf.constant(df_test),
    y=tf.constant(test_label)
    return x, y

df=df_train.select_dtypes(exclude=['object'])
numeric_cols=df.columns


df2=df_train.select_dtypes(include=['object'])
categorical_cols=df2.columns

model_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
estimator= tf.contrib.learn.LinearEstimator(model_dir=model_dir,
feature_columns=[numeric_cols,categorical_cols],
head=tf.contrib.learn.poisson_regression_head())

#train model
estimator.fit(input_fn=input_fn_train,steps=None, monitors=[])

#evaluate the model
results=estimator.evaluate(input_fn=input_fn_test)

print("model directory = %s" % model_dir)
for key in sorted(results):
  print("%s: %s" % (key, results[key]))


pred=list(estimator.predict(input_fn=input_fn_test))
```

Answer (score 0):

The way estimator `fit()`, `evaluate()` and `predict()` methods work is they attempt to load a saved model from `model_dir`. That is why you supply the `model_dir` when you create an estimator. `fit()` works even if there is no saved model and will save the model on regular, pre-defined intervals. `evaluate()` and `predict()` expect the saved model to exist. So you need to make sure that directory is available and contains the trained model.

In your case, you have `steps=None`, so I expect that the model is not actually getting trained and saved before attempting an evaluation. Why do you set steps to None?

Comment: Actually step=None is default value for fit() method. I put 500 instead of None and I removed the model_dir line , nothing changed I am getting stiil the same error.  Also I checked the directory is available but it's empty.

Comment: The reason steps=None by default is because there is more than one way to control the number of training iterations, you can set steps, max_steps or both. But you need to set at least one of them to the number of steps your want your model to train.